# Image downloading is not working in android. Looks like underscore is not supported

Tags: android

I am trying to download the image from the URL http://dbh_cache.s3.amazonaws.com/19445/34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f-33b64a2ed0f1ff4750f183b4f2a161b8.png

It seem the domain of the URL contains underscore which results in image download failure. Please let me know if i am correct

Comment: It would help if you show us how you're downloading the image.

Comment: Using Network image Loader class            DisplayImageOptions activity_images_option = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                    .cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(con.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_placeholder))
                    .handler(new Handler())
                    .cacheOnDisc(true).build();

            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(imageView, false);
            imageLoader.displayImage(path,

Comment: I also tried lot of other sdk like picaso,volley and networkimageloader but nothing works for me

Comment: try to run URL in AsyncTask may will get download from that URL

Comment: Show your code in your Question not in Comment. @Kiran Choudhary

Comment: It's working here with Fresco for example.

Comment: @PedroOliveira could you please share your code

Comment: @KiranChoudhary I'm using a library called Fresco to test this use case. It's from facebook. It's downloading the image with no problems

Comment: @KiranChoudhary Are you sure you have INTERNET permissions on your app?

Comment: @PedroOliveira yeah i have added internet permission and the image url is returning in the API. Can you please try this URL with Fresco SDK

Comment: Yes @KiranChoudhary and like I said it's working. That url is indeed working. Also, I just tested with UIL and it's working fine too with this code: https://gist.github.com/kanytu/2418876068187ae46454

Answer (score 0):

use Glide this is simple.

add this to your app gradle.

```
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
```

then use this single line of code. don't need to add Async Task.

```
 Glide.with(context).load(ImageUrl)
            .placeholder("drawable to show while loading image")
            .error("drawable to show if loading image fails")
            .into(imageView);
```

there are so many things you can do it with Glide check this [Link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

don't forget to add permissions to your manifest.

Comment: down voter can you please explain me the reason, why you down voted it?  It would help me in future.